# Add Cron Job to Function (node.js, express, react, mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, node-cron

Can you help me with cron function in my app? I'm stuck with it(

Here's my "track.controller.js" and "server.js" with "multiTrack" function. multiTrack() function starts re-crawling process by users URL's, it's starts manually via button in users dashboard, but i want to add cron job to this function (multiTrack).
Imported "multiTrack" function in server.js file return "req is not defined"...
Thank u!

/-----------server.js------------/

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
const multiTrackfunc = require('./controllers/track.controller.js');

cron.schedule("*/60 * * * * *", () => {
  try {
    multiTrackfunc.multiTrack(req, res, next);
    console.log(`Re-crawling starts via cron`);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(`${err} - in cron`);
  }
});
```

/-----------server.js------------/

/-----------track.controller.js------------/

```
const cron = require('node-cron')

exports.multiTrack = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { userId, createdTracks } = req.body;
    const trackIds = createdTracks.map((createdTrack) => createdTrack._id);

    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
        error: "User does not exist",
      });
    }

    try {
      // loop through each track START
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        createdTracks.forEach(async (createdTrack) => {
          const existingTrack = await Track.findById(createdTrack._id);
          if (!existingTrack) {
            reject();
          }
          
          // crawl Amazon product
          console.log(`${createdTrack.name} re-crawling starts`);
          const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
          const page = await browser.newPage();

          await page.goto(createdTrack.productUrl, {
            waitUntil: "networkidle2",
          });

          const crawledProduct = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let actualPrice = 0;

            const prepOurPrice = document.querySelector("span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").innerText;

            const image = document.querySelector(".woocommerce-product-gallery__image a img").src;
            const ourPrice = parseFloat(prepOurPrice.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g, ""));
            const salePrice = document.querySelector("#priceblock_saleprice");
            const dealPrice = document.querySelector("#priceblock_dealprice");

            ///parseFloat(actualPrice.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g, ""))

            if (ourPrice) {
              actualPrice = ourPrice;
            } else if (salePrice) {
              actualPrice = salePrice.innerText;
            } else if (dealPrice) {
              actualPrice = dealPrice.innerText;
            }

            return {
              image,
              actualPrice,
            };
          });
          console.log(`${createdTrack.name} re-crawling ends`);
          await browser.close();

          const { image, actualPrice } = crawledProduct;

          if (existingTrack.image !== image) {
            existingTrack.image = image;
            await existingTrack.save();
          }

          if (existingTrack.actualPrice !== actualPrice) {
            existingTrack.actualPrice = actualPrice;
            await existingTrack.save();
          }

          resolve();
        });
      });
      // loop through each track END
    } catch {
      return res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
        error: "Found invalid track id",
      });
    }

    const tracks = await Track.find({ _id: { $in: trackIds } });

    return res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      data: tracks,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("crawling failed");
    return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};
```

/-----------track.controller.js------------/

UPDATE

When I remove "req, res, next" from

```
cron.schedule("*/5 * * * * *", () => {
  try {
    multiTrackfunc.multiTrack();
    console.log(`Re-crawling starts via cron`);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(`${err} - in cron`);
  }
});
```

Looks like "multiTrack" starts, but with errors:
Terminal chronology:

```
crawling failed
Re-crawling starts via cron
/Work/Scrapers/webtools-tracker/controllers/track.controller.js:258
return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
at Object.exports.multiTrack (/Work/Scrapers/webtools-tracker/controllers/track.controller.js:258:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval).

> The setInterval() method, offered on the Window and Worker
> interfaces, repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet,
> with a fixed time delay between each call.

Comment: Thank you so much! After adding this code "setInterval(this.multiTrack, 10000);" after 
multiTrack function in "track.controller.js". Looks like crawling start, but return errors below:

crawling failed
[0] /Work/Scrapers/webtools-tracker/controllers/track.controller.js:258
[0]     return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
[0]                ^
[0] 
[0] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')